# Mapping & Reducing by key in a df

Tags: pyspark

First off - thank you for taking your time to read through my question.

I am trying to get a hang of Pyspark, but I am having trouble with the discrepancy between RDD and DF's in pyspark.

My Data: my data is structured as the following:

```
+-------+-------------+-------+------+-----+
|     ID|         date| ticker|Return| Year|
+-------+-------------+-------+----- +-----+
| 215021|2018-04-12   |  XYZ  | 0.21 | 2018|
| 205021|2018-04-13   |  XYZ  | 0.18 | 2018|
   ...       ...         ...    ...   ...
| 5102  |2012-01-14   |  ABC  | 0.21 | 2012|
| 5102  |2012-01-05   |  ABC  |-1.01 | 2012|
  ...       ...         ...    ...   ... 
+-------+-------------+-------+------+-----+
```

Essentially - I have a df of stocks and their returns. The columns I am really concerned about are Return and Year. I want to calculate the average return per year...

In Python it would be:

```
df.groupby('Year').sum()
```

However, I am really confused as to how to go about doing this in Pyspark. Here is some of my thought process and code I've tried thus far...

1. I am thinking I would need to create a `<key><value>` pair for each row, meaning my key would be `<year>` and value would be `<return>`. Perhaps using a mapping function? Not too sure , but here's what I tried to do:

   ```
   df.rdd.map(lambda y: (int(y[5]), float(y[4])))
   ```

   However, whenever I try and show the results, I get an error, meaning I am not even sure if my structure of this is even correct.
2. Calculating the sum per year - this would require me to `ReducebyKey(year)`... , so something along the lines:

   ```
   reduceByKey(year)
   ```

   However, I get the error

   ```
   NameError: name 'year' is not defined
   ```

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use dataframe operations since your data is already structured ... example group by aggregation using your dataset.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([([0.21, 2018]),
                           ([0.18, 2018]),
                           ([0.21, 2012]),
                           ([-1.01, 2012])], ["return", "year"])
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- return: double (nullable = true)
 |-- year: long (nullable = true)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.groupBy("year").agg(avg("return").alias("avg_return")).show()

+----+----------+
|year|avg_return|
+----+----------+
|2012|      -0.4|
|2018|     0.195|
+----+----------+
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Overall - DFs are Spark's high level structured API which have a schema/type just like Pandas and R DFs whereas RDDs are Spark's low level unstructured API which do not have a schema and are just raw (Python, Scala, Java) objects of type string.  Basically all DF Spark code compiles down to an RDD it is just in a structured tabular format.

Comment: thank you for that. I understand... I will leave the question open for a bit more, but I will choose your answer as the correct one at the end. Thanks again!